# Crystal Reports Record Filtering using and

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Currently I have a crystal report that only shows orders which included a "Storm Door" **OR** a "Sunroom Component".  However I would like it to only show orders that include BOTH "Storm Door" **AND** "Sunroom Component" within a order.  Any suggestions on how the code for this might look?

Comment: Could you include the code you have for the Or?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Right now my record selection formula is {Categories.Description} in ["BetterView Sunroom Components", "Storm Doors"]                   However I need to only show order numbers that include both "BetterView Sunroom Components and "Storm Doors".  If I use {Categories.Description} = "Storm Doors" and {Categories.Description}  = "BetterView Sunroom Compnents" then I still get the problem of duplicate order numbers, one for each category

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your own question - If you want the report to retrieve records where BOTH products were ordered, you would use an AND statement - `{Categories.Description} = "Storm Doors" and {Categories.Description} = BetterView Sunroom Compnents"`. However, the issue with duplicate records sounds like a problem with the design of the report. You could try a few things

1. Look at the table joins and verify they are setup correctly; if you have a 'one to many' join setup, you may be retrieving multiple rows for each record. If you joined Customer to Orders on the Customer_ID, you would get every single order for each customer, etc.
2. Click Database > Select Distinct Records - Depending on how your report is configured and which fields you are displaying, this may remove the undesired duplicates.
3. Change your grouping order - Instead of grouping by Category (Storm door, Subroom), group by Customer and then count the number of orders or use an aggregate function to give you the information you need.